# Pushing to Heroku and temporary data

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have now around 1 month of experience with Heroku, but I came accross this problem:

---

I deploy the node.js application to Heroku with *git push heroku main*. I made the news web site. The webpage with news gets the data from news.xml. You can also make new articles where you click button Submit and the inputed data goes into news.xml. But this news.xml is saved on Heroku and when I push my project again, it is all lost.

How can I prevent this? How can I send the data to one main source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku filesystem is ephemeral which means the changes are lost once the Dyno restarts (at least once a day). Everything you save locally gets lost.

If you can push your `news.xml` always from your repos then you can just redeploy the app everytime you have an update (not ideal but simple to do)

If you need to save changes (from a screen for example) into the `news.xml` you then need to use an external storage like a database (Postgres) or a remote storage (S3).

Comment: I will probably switch to MongoDB.